# Solution to Algorithm on Safe Breaking

Tags: algorithm

I have tried finding better algo and searched the internet but couldn't find one.
The question goes -

> Satish has a combination safe that consists of multiple rotating dials that are placed next to each other. Each dial is etched with digits 0 through 9, in order. At  any stage, exactly one of the digits on each dial is visible. The string formed by concatenating the visible digits of each dial is termed as the current combination. The visible digit on a dial can be changed by rotating the dial up or down. Rotating dial in increases the digit by 1 i.e 0 to 1, 1 to 2, and so on. The digits on the dial wrap around so a 9 is followed by 0. Rotating the dial down changes the digit in reverse direction.

We can rotate multiple adjacent dials at the same time. That is, in a single step we can take arbitrary number of consecutive dials, and rotate all of them one step in the same direction.

Satish is given the current combination (C) and the required combination (R) that unlocks the safe. Write a program to determine the minimum number of steps required to open the safe.

Input : 
986#007 
Output :
2

//Note - Here two keys are seperated by #

Comment: "I have tried finding better algo" -- better than *what*? Show what you have done so far. Otherwise, Stack Overflow isn't in the business of doing homework assignments.

Comment: Seems you need to learn about integer modulo operation

Comment: Exact dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51552605/9254539.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand this problem, I have an very easy solution. If you choose solve it by only one side rotation,  minimum number of steps should be the max up-rotation among the digits in the key, and the same for down-rotation. Otherwise, you can choose doing both up and down rotation: for each specific digit, you should choose a fewer step rotation; and the overall steps should be the sum of the max up-rotation and the max down-rotation.

```
    int maxDown = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < keyLength; i++) {
      maxDown = max((10+key1[i]-key2[i])%10, maxDown);
    }

    int maxUp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < keyLength; i++) {
      maxUp = max((10+key2[i]-key1[i])%10, maxUp);
    }

    int maxUp2 = 0;
    int maxDown2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < keyLength; i++) {
       int up = (10+key2[i]-key1[i])%10;
       int down = (10+key1[i]-key2[i])%10;
       if (up < down) {
           maxUp2 = max(up, maxUp2);
       }
       else {
           maxDown2 = max(down, maxDown2);
       }
    }
    int ans = min(maxUp, maxDown, maxUp2+maxDown2);

    return ans;
```

If I am wrong, please tell me an exception case.

Comment: Sorry, I think it should return 2 from maxUp, isn't it? maxUp = max(10+0-9, 10+0-8, (10+7-6)%10) = 2